# Table in loop dynamic values

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, loops

I have the following loop, showing me results from a certain page.

```
foreach($json->rooms as $room)
{
    echo '<p><b>' . $room->name . '</b></p>';

    foreach($room->meetings as $meeting)
    {
        echo '<p><b>' . $meeting->subject . '</b></p>'; 
        echo '<p><b>Organizor:</b> ' . $meeting->organizer . '</p>';
        echo '<p><b>Start:</b> ' . $meeting->start . '</p>';
        echo '<p><b>End:</b> ' . $meeting->end . '</p>';
        echo '<p><b>Duration:</b> ' . $meeting->duration . '</p>';          
    }
}
```

This shows me a result like:

```
Room 1
     Subject
          startTime
          endTime
          totalTime 
     Subject
          startTime
          endTime
          totalTime  Room 2
Room 2

Room 3

Room 4
```

As you can see, we have 4 rooms. in 1 room there are 2 appointments (at different times of the day).

My question:
With only 2 appointments, the screen won't be filled alot.
But if we have a appointment in every room, the page will get very long.

What i would like is something like this:

```
Room 1
     Subject              Subject
          startTime            startTime
          endTime              endTime
          totalTime            totalTime

Room 2

Room 3

Room 4
```

So that every appointment of the same room, will be next to the other of that room.

How do i do this while it is in a loop?

Comment: You (will) need a `<table>` for that sort of layout.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Not at all - thankfully we're not in the nineties anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, wrap the entire meeting in a `<div>` tag by adding `<div class="meeting">` to the very start of the first echo in the meeting loop. Then add a closing `</div>` to the end of the last echo in the meeting loop. Then you can use some CSS styling like the following to display this correctly:

```
.meeting {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This will make them sit inline - you can adjust the width to your preference.

**Edit**

You *could* use floats (`float:left`) but that add's a whole new level of complexity with the requirements of a clearfix, but you can read more on that here if you wish:

[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: Oh wauw, this did it. I feel soo stupid right now... But thanks!

Comment: Balls, I shouldn't have bothered writing a snippet and thus losing valuable time. =)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each subject in the same room inside its own `<section class='subject'>` (or `<div class='subject'>`, whatever you like) and use CSS (`display: inline-block;`) to make those `<section>`s go next to eachother instead of beneath eachother.

```css
.subject {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Schedule</h1>
<section class='room'>
  <h2>Room 1</h2>
  <section class='subject'>
    <h3>Subject 1.1</h3>
    <time>start</time>
    <time>end</time>
    <time>total</time>
  </section>
  <section class='subject'>
    <h3>Subject 1.2</h3>
    <time>start</time>
    <time>end</time>
    <time>total</time>
  </section>
</section>
<section class='room'>
  <h2>Room 2</h2>
</section>
<section class='room'>
  <h2>Room 3</h2>
  <section class='subject'>
    <h3>Subject 3.1</h3>
    <time>start</time>
    <time>end</time>
    <time>total</time>
  </section>
  <section class='subject'>
    <h3>Subject 3.2</h3>
    <time>start</time>
    <time>end</time>
    <time>total</time>
  </section>
</section>
<section class='room'>
  <h2>Room 4</h2>
</section>
```